# passing callback function pointer as parameter from vb code to c++ dll

Tags: c++, vb.net, interop

I am facing problems while calling c++ dll functions from vb project. I have a c++ dll function whose prototype is as follows:

```
bool registerCallbackOnDataRec(int groupID, void * func);
```

The 'func' is a callback function pointer which needs to have the following signature:

```
typedef struct
{
    DWORD senderIPAddr ;
    DWORD numOfBytes ;
    BYTE* buffer ;
} ReceivedMessage ;

void DataRecFromServerMcstGroup(ReceivedMessage *msg);
```

I am facing problems. I am not able to

1. pass a callback function pointer 'func' of type void* in VB.
2. declare a function of the specified signature in VB, that is, a function whose argument is a pointer to the structure 'ReceivedMessage'.
   I searched internet but could not find the answers. Anybody, please help.

**Edit:**
After Hans Passant comments, i have written some VB code to call the c++ function.

```
Public Delegate Sub DataRecFromServerDelegate(ByVal msg As IntPtr)

Declare Function registerCallbackOnDataRec Lib "NetDLL.dll" (ByVal groupID As Integer, ByVal funcPtr As DataRecFromServerDelegate)

Public Structure ReceivedMessage
    Public senderIpAddr As UInteger
    Public numOfBytes As UInteger
    Public buffer() As Byte
End Structure

Private Sub DataRecFromServerMcstGroup(ByVal msgPtr As IntPtr)
    If msgPtr <> 0 Then
        *** Here i am not able to cast msgPtr into ReceivedMessage object ***
        PacketRecordDLL(Msg.numOfBytes, Msg.buffer)
    End If
End Sub
...
Dim varFuncPtr As DataRecFromServerDelegate = AddressOf DataRecFromServerMcstGroup

registerCallbackOnDataRec(groupID_Recording, varFuncPtr)
```

But this is not working. In this code i am not able to fill up the gap in the code where to cast the msgPtr into ReceivedMessage object. I am not sure whether rest of the code is correct or not. Any help.

Comment: You have to declare a Delegate that matches the function pointer.  Probably needs the [UnmanagedFunctionPointer] attribute to declare it Cdecl.  Declare a Structure to match the ReceivedMessage, the buffer member needs to be IntPtr.  Acces the data in the buffer with Marshal.ReadByte().

Comment: I have made edit to the post. Please reply back.

Comment: *the buffer member needs to be IntPtr*.  Not the delegate argument, it needs to be ReceivedMessage.  If it seems to contain junk in your callback then you do need the attribute.